# What's the SPSite do in the Register-SPWorkflowService command?

Tags: workflow, 2013, administration

The [`Register-SPWorkflowService`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj663115.aspx) command has a required property `SPSite`. MSDN says

> Specifies a site collection to configure.

To [register the workflow service with SharePoint](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj658588.aspx) I would have to run the following:

```
Register-SPWorkflowService –SPSite "http://myserver/mysitecollection" –WorkflowHostUri "http://workflow.example.com:12291" –AllowOAuthHttp
```

All good so far, I just don't understand what the SPSite is for. When I try to register the workflow service for another site, e.g. "mysitecollection2", I get an error that the farm is already registered with the workflow service, so there can be only one association I assume?

What is the SPSite parameter for? What happens when said site is deleted? What happens when I run workflows on other sites - they do work, I know - but why the site then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a poorly named parameter, and the TechNet documentation does not describe it at all. I figured this out with some trial and error when configuring.

The SPSite parameter can be any site collection in any web application, and basically configures a Workflow Service Application Proxy to connect SharePoint to Workflow Manager. It doesn't matter which web application or site collection you use, just that it exists, and unless you are doing subscriptions/multi-tenant, you only have to run it once on the farm.

The Workflow Service Application Proxy is added to the default proxy group, so SharePoint 2013 workflows should now work for any web application in your farm that uses the default proxy group. If you are using custom proxy groups, you will need to edit and select the Workflow Service Application Proxy in order for SharePoint 2013 workflow to work with that particular web application.

Comment: have some virtual +1 upvotes. Great info, also the additional proxy information.

Comment: good find Chris! +1

Comment: in my IIS, am not able to see the workflow management site .what may be wrong ?