# what should -SPSite & -WorkflowHostUri refer to when configuring Workflow manager for sharepoint server 2016

Tags: installation, configuration, 2016, workflow-manager, farm

I am working on new sharepoint server 2016. and i have installed Workflow manager inside sharepoint server 2016, by following the steps mentioned here :-

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/34407.sharepoint-2016-step-by-step-installation-of-workflow-manager.aspx

Now i successfully finished the following steps:-

1. Install the Microsoft Web Platform Installer 5.0
2. Installation of Workflow Manager 1.0 CU 2
3. Apply Cumulative Update 3.0 for Workflow Manager 1.0
4. Configure the Workflow Manager
5. Install the WorkFlow Manager Client on SharePoint Server

But when i want to do this steps "Register Workflow Proxy for SharePoint Servers", i am not sure what i need to provide for this command:-

```
Register-SPWorkflowService -SPSite "..." -WorkflowHostUri "..."
```

i mean what should `-SPSite` refer to ? and what should `-WorkflowHostUri` refer to ?

Comment: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/34462.sharepoint-2016-step-by-step-guide-to-register-workflow-service-proxy.aspx

Comment: @Christoffer so what does "_-SPSite: URL of Site collections.
-WorkflowHostURI: Workflow Host URI is the URL of the Workflow site._" really mean? can you explain this ?

Comment: @Christoffer now the link you refer to does not explain from where i can know the values for -SPSite & -WorkflowHostURI  ?? i mean from where i can get these values?

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/71767/whats-the-spsite-do-in-the-register-spworkflowservice-command

Comment: And the workflow uri should be the adress + port to the actual workflow manager server application as mentioned here http://www.harbar.net/articles/wfm2.aspx

Comment: @Christoffer ok i understand that . so for the SPSite seems that i can use any site collection... but is there any best practice if i should create a unique site collection for the workflow and do not allow users to access it?,, or it is fine if i just use an existing site collections which is being used by users?

Comment: The team were obvious drunk when they wrote the documentation. The SPSite parameter can be any site collection, if you are unsure just create a new site collection and leave it as be. 2013 Workflows will be available to use in any site collection no matter what.

Answer (score 5):

To register a workflow service to a specific site collection you should run `Register-SPWorkflowService` cmdlet that requires providing the below parameter values

`-SPSite` it denotes to the site collection URL that you need to use the workflow service on it.

**Note:**

> It seems that each site collection needs to be registered with workflow
>   service. But actually it’s not 100% correct, once you have registered a workflow service to
>   any SharePoint site collection within the farm, it will be enabled for all SharePoint
>   web applications / site collections. I am pretty sure from this
>   behavior and that what I got on my farm.

`-WorkflowHostUri` this is the URL of the workflow service that hosted on IIS and created during the configuration of Workflow manager.

[image]

**How you can get this information:**

- For `-SPSite` As mentioned above you just you need to specify your site collection that you need to use the workflow service on it.
- For `-WorkflowHostUri` If you have installed the WFM on the same SharePoint farm so the WorkflowHostUri should be as `http://"web application":12291` for HTTP and `https://"web application":12290`. or by opening the IIS to check as above mentioned

**Note:** this port is specified during configuring WFM at this step

[image]

You can also get it via PowerShell  `Get-WFFarm | select httpport,httpsport`

For more details check

- [Install and Configure Workflow Manager for SharePoint](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/05/06/install-and-configure-workflow-manager-for-sharepoint-2013/)
- [Register-SPworkflowservice unable to connect to the remote service during registering the Workflow Manager in SharePoint](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/01/12/register-spworkflowservice-unable-to-connect-to-the-remote-service/)

Comment: thanks for the reply.. so when you say to specify the site collection i want to use the workflow on it... then what if i need the workflow on more than one site collection ?? i think i am missing something..

Comment: and if i need to only define a single site collection inside the  -SPSite parameters.. then should this site collection be a unique site that does not have data inside it.. or i can use existing site collection which is being used by end users??

Comment: @johnG existing site collection or new site collection it doesn't matter

Comment: To avoid the confusion:  it seems, each site collection need to be registered with workflow service. But it’s not correct, registering a single SharePoint site collection, will enable workflow manager for all SharePoint web applications/site collections. I am pretty sure from this behavior and that what i got in my farm